# Failure to find external:authapi:jar:2005-08-12

Tags: maven, svn, openam

Compile openam checked out from svn, and get an error:

> Failed to execute goal on project openam-auth-securid: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.forgerock.openam:openam-auth-securid:jar:13.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find external:authapi:jar:2005-08-12 in http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of forgerock-staging-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Is it a network problem? Did someone meet it before?

Answer (score 0):

The authapi library has been removed from the Maven repository, as there were redistribution issues. In order to build older OpenAM releases you will need to download older OpenAM releases and install the authapi library manually to your local Maven repository.